# Backbone adding more events after render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

How do I add more events after rendering a collection to a view.

I have a list of all the element Ids which need an event binded to them.

Currently I am trying to use jQuery onclick to trigger a callback to a function in my view.

The problem though is that the function call in my view is undefined inside the jQuery click event.

I looked at the Backbone docs and it says to use delegateEvents however the documentation does not show examples ....

http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#View-delegateEvents

```
//add more dynamic events for the rendered employee list 
    addMoreEvents: function ()
    {
        console.log("List View - Add More DOM Events");


        for (var i = 0; i < this.employees.models.length; i++)
        {
            var element = "#" + this.employees.models[i].attributes.id;
            //bind event that when user clicks on <li> on employeelist , it will go fetch all the tasks for that employee
            $(element).click(this.getEmployeeInfo()); //not working!
        }


    }
```

There must be an easy way to do this for adding events to elements that exist after being rendered.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. Instead of trying to bind directly to click events on `#some-id` elements, you should attach a class to the things you want to click on and then bind click handlers to elements of that class using the view's normal `events` object.

For example, you'd have something like this in the HTML inside your view's `el`:

```
<li class="item" id="6">Where</li>
<li class="item" id="11">is</li>
<li class="item" id="23">pancakes</li>
<li class="item" id="42">house?</li>
```

and then you'd have `events` like this in your view:

```
events: {
    'click .item': 'getEmployeeInfo'
}
```

Then your click handler, `getEmployeeInfo`, can look at `ev.currentTarget.id` to get the `id` attribute of the clicked item:

```
getEmployeeInfo: function(ev) {
    var id = ev.currentTarget.id; // this will be the model's `id`
    // do whatever needs to be done...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. 

Please add this code to your question to show how to access dom elements

`ev.currentTarget.getAttribute("attributename");`

Comment: What does `getAttribute` have to do with the question?